# Is it possible ot use JAXB in Android

Tags: android, xml, jaxb

I'm creating Android project generated in Maven and I have add dependency for JAXB-API but it's throwing an exception in line

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("my_package");
```

does anyone know is it even possible to use it under Android or maybe someone has simillar problem?

The XML file is in assets and I'm getting it by getAssets() but in that place is another problem but I don't know what?

Comment: Keep in mind that JAXB is not lightweight and maybe heavy if it's phone app or something with low resources (I don't know - for tablet it maybe OK, never really done Android projects with JAXB, only Java Desktop). Can't you use an alternative for your XML operations?

Comment: A server side apps is using jaxb and as rulle says "Do not repeat yoursef" I have an API wich contains necessary elements to unmarshal XML so it'll be nice to use that... I noticed that when I was trying to add manually dependencies it have a problem with conversion to Dalvik format but in application which I mentioned I'm using maven-archetypes... Maybe it needs some plugin? :/

Comment: I assume you already use the maven-android-plugin. http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/ I have no experience using Maven in Andriod apps, so I cannot offer any further help.

Comment: Well probably I have solution it's not possible to use JAXB in nadorid because it's using Java 1.5 but JAXB requires 1.6 and even you will build external jar to import into android project it'll return exception because it can not translate to dalvik format.

Comment: @hovanessyan "Keep in mind that JAXB is not lightweight" - I wrote a JAXB for JavaScript (see Jsonix) so I personally don't think that JAXB is too heavy. I think I know what my next open-source project will be. :)

Comment: well 'not too heavy' and 'not lightweight' is more or less the same meaning. I agree with you, but for a phone app there's lighter libraries in general. But he already got dependency on JAXB because of the server side.

Comment: Ok we changed JAXB to SimpleFramework on server side it's quite simillar much more light... :D

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in response to the other post on this topic, I've repackaged JAXB.  See [this blog](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/) for details.